# Unable to run a 32-bit program on 64-bit VM

Tags: 64-bit, virtualization

I compiled a small "hello world" C program on Ubuntu 10.04 32 bit machine. Then I put the executable(a.out) on Ubuntu 12.10(64 bit) VMWare virtual machine and tried to execute it(./a.out). The OS does not identify the file and says 'No such file or directory'. But when I put the same executable on a Ubuntu 12.10(64 bit) running on a 64 bit laptop, it runs fine and I get the desired output.
The VM is running on IBM Blade Servers. I wanted to know why the results for a VM?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The message `No such file or directory` does not refer to your executable file: `a.out`. Instead it refers to a *helper program* that’s needed to run the 32 bit *dynamically linked* executable `a.out`.

Now, I found all of these very well explained in this nice article:

- [About running 32 bit programs on 64 bit Ubuntu and shared libraries](http://www.markusbe.com/2009/09/about-running-32-bit-programs-on-64-bit-ubuntu-and-shared-libraries/)

> **Static and dynamic linkage**
>
> There are two types of binary executables: statically linked and
>   dynamically linked ones. First about the *statically linked* ones: When
>   a program wants to call a library function, it refers to it by name.
>   When building the program from source, all library functions used in
>   the program are copied from the library into the program. The program
>   then contains its own code as well as the code of the library
>   functions it uses. Then in the calling places the name is changed to
>   the address of the corresponding function in the program. This process
>   is called *linking* because it links together the name of a function
>   with the function itself, its implementation. It’s called *static*,
>   because the link cannot be changed after the program has been built.
>
> *Dynamically linked* programs work differently: The program also refers
>   to library functions by name. When building the program, two lists are
>   assembled and stored together with the program: a list of which
>   library functions are used in which places, and a list of the
>   libraries that contain the functions used by the program. That’s all
>   for building the program.
>
> Later, at *execution time*, a special helper program, the so-called
>   dynamic linker, looks in specific places in the file system for each
>   library on the library list and loads it into memory. Now the dynamic
>   linker knows at what memory addresses the library functions are
>   available. It uses the first list to write the correct address in all
>   places that call library functions. Then the dynamically linked
>   program can be run.

Comment: This "No file found" error message confused me too the first time °͜°, then I understood it meant some file required by the app was missing.

Comment: @Radu Rădeanu, what do you call a *helper program*? I guess a dynamically linked library. If so, calling it a *helper program* just muddles the explanation.

Comment: Here is a link I found useful for understanding this issue - [Getting “Not found” message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system/13409#13409)