# Explaining "-bash: No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, bash

Why would bash claim that a file doesn't exist when it clearly does?

```
$ ls -l a
-r-x------ 1 configurator configurator 3904 Dec  7 10:36 a

$ file a
a: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped

$ ./a
-bash: ./a: No such file or directory
```

Comment: are you using 32bit Ubuntu?

Comment: No, 64-bit. `Linux koandev 3.11.0-14-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 17:04:55 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: To everyone who's closed this question as a duplicate: Thanks. I very much appreciate the link for more information, and would never have found that answer myself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You get this error because you try to run a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit operating system.

And the message `No such file or directory` does not refer to your executable file called `a`. Instead the error it refers to a ***helper program*** that's needed to run the 32-bit dynamically linked executable `a`.

You can find more information referring to static and dynamic linkage [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/353497/147044).

Comment: I just wish the error message was a little friendlier and told me which file it couldn't find so I wouldn't have had to ask this question in the first place...

Answer (score 3):

The problem likely isn't the file you're trying to run, but a file it depends on. Run `ldd` on the file to see if any of its dependencies can't be found.

Comment: Interesting. This sounds right, but `ldd` doesn't help, it just says: `adsd:
        not a dynamic executable`