# bash ./ no such file or directory, how to find what missing?

Tags: bash, error-handling

Here is and error which Im getting

```
$ ./idaq
bash: ./idaq: No such file or directory
```

Yes a readed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388374/explaining-bash-no-such-file-or-directory) and whole google page about this error but I could not find an answer, here is whats idaq requires

```
readelf -d idaq | grep NEEDED
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libida.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libQtXml.so.4]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libQtGui.so.4]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libQtCore.so.4]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

when I run ldd here is what I get

```
 ldd idaq
    not a dynamic executable
```

All required files are present what am I missing ?

Comment: Possibly the executable is for a different architecture? what are the outputs of `file idaq` and `uname -m`?

Comment: file idaq
    idaq: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=cb4206d57fa4791114a9ba3958922bf541d95725, stripped
and 
    uname -m
    x86_64

Comment: I musta add program idaq was working just fine a day ago

Comment: I did tried strace but same error strace ./idaq
strace: Can't stat './idaq': No such file or directory

Comment: So based on your `uname` and `file` outputs, it is a 32-bit ELF executable but your system is 64-bit - it's likely failing to run because it can't find 32-bit versions of the shared libraries