# bash: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, gtk

I've written a simple C program that uses the GTK+ visual interface (I can post the code if it's relevant). I can compile it without erros or warnings using:

```
gcc -c s9p2.c 
pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0
```

Where s9p2.c is the program name. However, when I try to run the program I get this:

```
bash: ./s9p2: No such file or directory
```

I have checked with the ls command and the file is in fact there. I have also tried to install. I have tried googling for a solution, and one that came up was to install the ia32-libs package. I did that, but it did not work.

I would appreciate any help. Please forgive me if I was not clear.

EDIT: As asked, this is the output of ls -l s9p2* is:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 francisco francisco 2492 Jan  3 19:11 s9p2.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 francisco francisco 6616 Jan  3 21:13 s9p2.o
```

Comment: Does this help? [Unable to run a 32-bit program on 64-bit VM](http://askubuntu.com/q/351827)

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -l s9p2*` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main error is adding the `-c` flag to your command - that tells `gcc` to **compile** the source file (producing an *object code* file `s9p2.o`) but stop short of **linking** it with the libraries necessary to create an executable program (`s9p2`)

The correct command should be something like

```
gcc -o s9p2 `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` s9p2.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

or

```
gcc -o s9p2 s9p2.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

Answer (score 0):

First the c file is not the program, the binary executable which should be called `s9p2` (no extension) unless you specified something different which compiling. Assuming you have compiled to an executable you need to make it executable as a program if it is not already:

The file is not executable, try running:

```
chmod +x s9p2
```